# How to allow anonymous user register Civicrm event without create drupal account

Tags: 7, civicrm

I'm using D7 CiviCRM 4.4.6.

I had a civicrm event with profile fields for user to fill in.

Anonymous users are allowed to register the event and create civicrm profile.

But there is a "Username" field, which force anonymous user to create a drupal user account when registering the event.

Is there anyway which anonymous user can register in my event, creating profile, without create a drupal user account?

Comment: There is now a public beta of a CiviCRM Stack Exchange site - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com - and pretty active it is too. I would recommend that you post future questions like this one there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the profile that you are using for the event registration and under advanced settings (at the bottom)

select "No account create option" radio and "save"

Good luck!